# Vercel Go Runtime can't access the binary file

Tags: go, serverless, vercel

I created a REST API with Go and deployed it to vercel with [github.com/tbxark/g4vercel](https://github.com/tbxark/g4vercel).

This is my project structure:

```
- api > index.go
- go.mod
- go.sum
- vercel.json
- X (this is the CLI tool binary written in Golang)
```

Now, within the `index.go` file, I have this code:

```
cliPath := "./X"
helpCmd := exec.Command(cliPath, "--help")
```

But vercel cannot find this binary when executing the command above. It shows this error:

```
fork/exec ./X: no such file or directory
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks.